# draw sprite on where mouse clicked

Tags: three.js

I am noobie to three.js, after reading https://threejs.org/examples/?q=inter#canvas_interactive_cubes , I want to add a function draw points where i clicked to my project(load and display stl files), I used the formula in that example,

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

but I found when the sprite is not drawn on where i clicked, but a little lower, you can see at http://static.medi-tool.cn/share/ds1/index.html (first click on the model will draw a sprite, second will draw a sprite and calculate the distance between two point, then two sprite will be removed in 2 seconds). can anyone tell me why? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it is because I have a div up to the canvas, when using the formula, i have to minus the height of that div, in other words, when calculate mouse.x, mouse.y, 'event.clientX' & 'event.clientY' should be relative to the canvas, not viewport.

The test page in the Question is OK now.